# AppBarLayout not showing Samsung Tablet 4.4.4

Tags: android, toolbar, android-appbarlayout

My app works fine on all the versions upto 6.0. However, on **Samsung 7" tablet Version 4.4.4** the **AppBarLayout** is not visible.It completely disappears as if there's no toolbar. It works fine on any other same sized **tablet**.
Following is my View Containers.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/topBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="105dp"
    android:background="#7F7F7F"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:background="#7F7F7F"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgBack"
                android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgGoTo"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:src="@drawable/pages" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvPageNumber"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgGoTo"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgBack"
                android:layout_width="31dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/menu_1" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/appbar_bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

and here's my

> **style.xml**

file.

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_darker</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.Dark.Dialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#000</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/primary</item>
</style>
```

Please find the screenshots attached, 
**left side** (Samsung 7") which **represent the issue**. 
**Right side**: nexus 5 (5.1) **required look**.
[image]

Comment: You should maybe add some screenshot of the problem, and describe what you found when debugging (is the view 'there' and visible?) your code and looking at the view hierarchy with the device monitor

Comment: No , The view is not there.The view is not visible at all. It doesnt become transparent of anything like that , because i have 3 icons there with click listener. I didnt get anything in the listener. 
This is the problem with Samsung Tablet only on 4.4.4. It works fine on any other tablet of same size with same version.